# Difference Between POS Entry Modes (Field 22)

Tags: iso8583, magnetic-cards

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand difference between `ISO 8583 Field 22` i.e. POS Entry Mode. I already know that:

- `52` means ICC Card
- `80` in case of fallback

But what I want to know is difference between

- `22` (Magnetic Stripe)
- and `90`

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @FaizenRabbani  I can probably give a very in-depth answer, but can your question is really broad as to covering every DE22 variant and the scenarios (as there are MANY). Is the root of your question what is the difference between a value of a magnetic stripe variants `02` and `90`?

Comment: F90 is mostly vendor-specific. the first two digits of that field as correspond to the Card Input Capability that's present on the terminal (Position 1) and the Input Mode used for that transaction (Position 2) - "22" here now corresponds to Mag. Stripe for both fields

Comment: @CRSouser Yes it is magnetic stripe variants.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The length of Field 22 usually 3-digits (or 4-digits in case it is BCD packed into two Bytes) in protocols based on ISO 8583:1987 or 12-digits in case protocols based on ISO 8583:1993 version. Customized protocols could use different sub-fields content and values meaning behind.

While you use short values in the requested question, I guess, your Field 22 based on ISO 8583:1987 version and you lost the leading and/or ending zero. So, your sample values becomes 3 digits length - `052`, `800`, `022`, and `090` or `900`.

Usually the 3-digits Field 22 splited into two sub-fields:

- Position 1 and 2 - Personal Account Number (PAN) Entry (or capability);
- Position 3 - Personal Identification Number (PIN) Entry (or capability);

Here are the possible interpretations:

- `02` - PAN auto-entry via magnetic stripe, track data is not required, `2` - no PIN.
- `05` - PAN auto-entry via chip, `2` - no PIN.
- `09` - E-Commerce, `0` - unknown PIN capability.
- `80` - Fallback to magnetic stripe, `0` - unknown PIN capability.
- `90` - PAN auto-entry via magnetic stripe, track data should be transmitted within the authorization request, `0` - unknown PIN capability.

etc.

`90` used in case track data present in the ISO 8583 request message, `02` - if, for same reason, acquirer or terminal device not qualified to transfer track data in the request messages.

Depending of protocol requirements could be exceptions with Field 22 values. It is usually checked during the terminal device and communication interface certifications.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. Do you know where I can find a detailed specification document that lists out all of the sub-fields for each data element?

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate few things here. From above comments I can see that 09 is for E commerce transactions,but as per my knowledge for E commerce transactions we should use PAN Entry mode as 01(manual entry). Because for card not present transactions entry mode has always in manually.

POS Entry mode says whether the particular transaction is E commerce or POS. The possible values are :

01 Manual entry

02 Magnetic Stripe,track 2 data will ignore

05 Smart card,track 2 data required

90 Magnetic stripe no track 2 data

91 contactless card

95 Smart card ,  track2 data not required

Thanks share your ideas on this

Answer (score 1):

```
POS_ENTRY_MODE_UNKNOWN         = 0x00, // Unknown
POS_ENTRY_MODE_MANUAL          = 0x01, // Manually Transcribed
POS_ENTRY_MODE_MSR             = 0x02, // Legacy Magstripe Read
POS_ENTRY_MODE_BARCODE         = 0x03, // Barcode Scan
POS_ENTRY_MODE_OCR             = 0x04, // OCR Scan
POS_ENTRY_MODE_ICC_WITH_CVV    = 0x05, // Chip read with manual entry of CVV
POS_ENTRY_MODE_ICC_CONTACTLESS = 0x07, // Contactless EMV
POS_ENTRY_MODE_MSR_FALLBACK    = 0x80, // Magstripe fallback (after chip read failure)
POS_ENTRY_MODE_MSR_WITH_CVV    = 0x90, // Legacy Magstripe with manual entry of CVV
POS_ENTRY_MODE_MSD_CONTACTLESS = 0x91, // Contactless Magstripe Data
POS_ENTRY_MODE_ICC_CONTACT     = 0x95, // Contact EMV
POS_ENTRY_MODE_AS_PER_ORIGINAL = 0x99, // Used for adjustment after card no longer present, e.g. to add a tip
```